# ASP.NET Repeater datasource bound to a function. Would it call the function twice?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, repeater

In the code behind I have a function that returns a List(Of SomeClass):

rptRepeater.DataSource = SomeFunction(SomeVariable)
rptRepeater.DataBind()

In the html I have a basic repeater layout and am using the below code to get the Properties of each object returned.

My question is, would there ever be a case that it would execute the Function more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only call the function per the number of times you call rptRepeater.DataBind().

And also, the code

```
<%#Databinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Parameter1")%>
```

can be shortened to

```
<%# Eval("Parameter1") %>
```

Comment: Turns out my problem wasn't an issue of Binding twice.  The problem was that users were able to fire the event twice and it looked like it was binding twice.